# How to change ion-spinner on windows platform

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

My windows phone application shows the ios spinner by default. I was wondering how to change that, because this default spinner is not animated on the windows phone platform. Therefore I want to show the android spinner by default, since this is the only one which uses javascript for animations. The other [ion spinners](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/) are animated by SMIL animations, which are not supported on IE ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31926601/5159481)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way i found until now is to set the default spinner to 'android' in the `angular.config` part in my application:

```
myApp.config( moduleConfig );
function moduleConfig( $ionicConfigProvider ) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.platform.default.spinner.icon( "android" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks this helped me out, but for other people that might run into this.... if you have an $ionicLoading template in your controller setting the default above will not override the value.  You would need to use the above and remove the icon from the templates.

Before:

```
template: '<p class="icon ion-loading-a"><ion-spinner class="spinner-assertive" icon="bubbles"/></p>';
```

After:

```
template: '<p class="icon ion-loading-a"><ion-spinner class="spinner-assertive"/></p>'
```